# Trying to set up a remote desktop connection via ssh proxy

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop

I am trying to use Remote Desktop to connect to a Windows server that is on a private LAN. I am doing this via an ssh proxy through a Linux server on the private LAN. I can ssh to the Linux server but so far I've been unable to use it as a springboard to the Windows server.

ssh access to a Linux server on the private LAN is via a dedicated port.

```
ssh -p <port> sssg@localhost
```

I have been trying to set up a proxy on a Linux box that will enable me to set up a remote desktop connection from my laptop. This is the syntax I've been using thus far.

```
ssh -L 3389:windows-server.whoi.edu:3389 linux-box.whoi.edu
```

If I'm understanding the ssh documentation correctly, this should enable me to set up a remote desktop session to windows-server by specifying "localhost" as the server, but so far I've kept getting an error message.
[image]

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: Are you sure port 3389 is free on the system that establishes the SSH connection? Better try to use a different local port and change the connection string in the RDP client accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried using port 3388 and vnc viewer gave me a different error: "The connection closed unexpectedly". On the linux server, this appeared on the console: "channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out"

Comment: Make sure you only change the local port not the remote one.

Comment: Your connect is succeeding. Windows is refusing to let you start another RDP (Remote Desktop) session. Close the other RDP session first.